# How to add 2 rows of different images using collection view in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

[View Image here..See section circled with black ink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF33k.png) l want to add a second row to the Collection view in my project. This second row is suppose to be horizontal list the first one and consist of different images

l have tried adding another image tag to the collection view template but it does solve my problem as it repeats the same images twice. Find my code below

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding sliders}" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="150" >
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <ListItemsLayout>
            <x:Arguments>
                <ItemsLayoutOrientation>Horizontal</ItemsLayoutOrientation>    
            </x:Arguments>
        </ListItemsLayout>           
     </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>        
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="#282626" Padding="0,5,0,0" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding Url}"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="160"
                       WidthRequest="160" 
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                 <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White" />       
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The code above adds a collections view with one row to the project.
Kindly help me add a second row with different images.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear (an image would help) but I don't think CollectionView will do what you want.

Comment: Add another Image in the grid and set it to Grid.row =1, then binding with a second url? Add a image to describe what you want to achieve would make us easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `CollectionView` element displays one row per object in your `Source` (in this case, "sliders"). So, in order to create another row, you have to simply add another object to your "sliders" list with the image you want to be displayed in the second row.

Adding another `Image` to the `DataTemplate` will not work because it will be referencing the same object, and if you're using the same property as the image source (in this case, "Url"), it will display the same image.